# Multi table association with Spring data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm trying to create DB solution for my Customer Offer requirement. I have to read a file and store the data in multiple tables which are mostly associated to each other.

I've created Entity classes and their associations as below. But with the current approach I see an issue expanding the offers from Coupons to Rewards. If I create another entity for Rewards then I need to update my `CustomerEntity` class and add another `@OneToMany` association with the new entity.

```
@Entity(name = "METADATA")
public class MetadataEntity {
    Metadata Id
    Offer description
     //Setters & Getters
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class CustomerEntity {
    Customer Id
    Customer Name
    CouponEntity (OneToMany - Join column Coupon Code)
     //Setters & Getters
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "PROFILE")
public class ProfileEntity {
    Profile Id
    CustomerEntity (OneToOne - Join Column Customer Id)
     //Setters & Getters
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "COUPON")
public class CouponEntity {
    Coupon Code
    Amount
    Expiry
     //Setters & Getters
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "OFFER")
public class OfferEntity{
    Id
    MetadataEntity(ManyToOne - Join column Metadata Id)
    ProfileEntity(ManyToOne - Join column Profile Id)
    //Setters & Getters
}
```

And from my DAO class I'm using `OfferRepository` class associated with Offer.

```
@Repository
public interface OfferRepository extends JpaRepository<OfferEntity, String> {}
```

```
@Autowired
OfferRepository offerRepo;

public class DaoImpl {
    createOffer(OfferEntity offer){
        offerRepo.save(offer);
    }

    readOffers(){
       offersList = offerRepo.findAll();
       for-each offer:offersList {
           //access all customer information & offer information (could be a coupon or rewards)
           offer.getProfile().getCustomer().getCoupons();
       }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to identify a solution where I don't need to update any of my existing entity classes in if I'm expanding the Offers.

Comment: Ever thought to use inheritance?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes, I gave it a thought but I was confused on how to read the child class information from parent class. I tried extending Customer entity from Coupon entity. But when reading offer details to get the coupon details how is it possible to read the Coupon details in this approach ````offer.getProfile().getCustomer().getCoupons()?```` does this work? and what would be the code to read Rewards points ````offer.getProfile().getCustomer().getRewards()?````

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a base class for Coupon and Rewards. Let's call it Benefit.

This can then be used as the relationship in the Customer class.

The customer class then could have a method to get either Coupons or Rewards depending on the class object you pass to that method like:

```
T List<T> getBenefits(Class<T> type)
```